# Issue when using callbacks in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have a situation where I have a function (named `onGetCameras`) that accepts a callback function (e.g., `getCamerasSuccess`); the intention is to call `onGetCameras` (which is an external function), which, does an AJAX call, and upon completion, calls `getCamerasSuccess`, passing the result it received.

What I have is something like this:

```
// My 'actionCreators' variable is a reference to create my actions
function* getCamerasSaga(action: action.GetCameras) {
  const { onGetCameras } = action;

  const getCamerasSuccess = function*(response: GetCamerasResponse) {
    console.log('SUCCESS', response);
    yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasSuccess(response);
  }

  yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasStart());

  yield call(onGetCameras, getCamerasSuccss);
}

export function* watchCamera() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.GetCameras, getCamerasSaga);
}
```

I can't figure out why it's not going into my `getCamerasSuccess` function: I never see my `console.log` message inside of that function

But, if I change my success callback to be a normal function, e.g.:

```
const getCamerasSuccess = (response: GetCamerasResponse) => {
  console.log('RESPONSE', response);
}
```

I can see that I'm receiving my response, but, as I mentioned, using the generator function, it seems that it never goes inside of that function.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getCamerasSuccess` isn't called because when you call a function it gets executed but when you call a generator function it only returns an iterator object on which you have to keep calling `next` for it to execute.

Your code would still not work though, because you are trying to use saga effect in a generator that is not under redux-saga control. If you want to keep working with callbacks you might be interested in the cps effect ( https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#cpsfn-args ). The callback has to be in node.js style though (first param err, second result).

Your code could then look like this:

```
function* getCamerasSaga(action: action.GetCameras) {
  const { onGetCameras } = action;

  yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasStart());
  try {
    const response: GetCamerasResponse = yield cps(onGetCameras);
    console.log('SUCCESS', response);
    yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasSuccess(response));
  } catch(err) { /* ... */ }
}
```

If modifying the `onGetCameras` API isn't an option you will have to either use normal function as callback and then use `store.dispatch` instead of `put` or you can create some small utility function with eventChannel (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html).

E.g.:

```
...
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga';

function createCbChannel(fn) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    fn((response) => {
      emitter(response);
      emitter(END);
    });
    return () => emitter(END);
  });
}

function* getCamerasSaga(action: action.GetCameras) {
  const { onGetCameras } = action;

  yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasStart());

  const cbChannel = yield call(createCbChannel, onGetCameras);
  const response: GetCamerasResponse = yield take(cbChannel);
  console.log('SUCCESS', response);
  yield put(actionCreators.getCamerasSuccess(response));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin for the answer. `cps` seems to do the trick for me. Just one question: I'm using TypeScript, so what should be the type of `onGetCameras` because right now, when I do `yield cps(onGetCameras)`, it complains that property `context` is missing on the type I have given to it  ---  To make it work, I did this: `yield cps(onGetCameras.bind(null))`, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it

Comment: I have literally 0 experience with typescript, but quick googling ravealed that a) if there are multiple type definitions for a function and you fail them then typescript will show you only the last one (might explain why it complains about context) b) this is an cps callback interface: `interface CpsCallback<R> {
  (error: any, result: R): void;
  cancel?(): void;
}`

Comment: Thank you anyways for the original answer, it helped a lot :)